# Sorting an object array alphabetically in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

Im trying to sort the name of the link alphabetically, but it says **level2.sort is not a function** any help is appreciated!

```
for (let i = 0, l = finalData.length; i < l; i++) {
        const level1 = finalData[i];
        console.log('This is level 1', level1);
        for (let x = 0, y = finalData[i].links.length; x < y; x++) {
            const level2 = finalData[i].links[x];
            level2.sort((a, b) => a.name - b.name);
            console.log('This is level 2', level2);
        }
    }
```

> Level 1 at [0] is {title: "resources" , links:Array(3)}
>
> Level 2 at [0] is {name: "google", path:"www.google.com"}
>
> Level 2 at [1] is {name: "yahoo", path:"www.yahoo.com"}
>
> Level 2 at [2] is {name: "apple", path:"www.apple.com"}
>
> ---
>
> Level 1 at [1] is {title: "TeacherEmails" , links:Array(2)}
>
> Level 2 at [0] is {name: "JoneA", path:"JoneA@yahoo.com"}
>
> Level 2 at [1] is {name: "AndyK", path:"AndyK@apple.com"}
>
> and so on

Comment: what are the outputs of the `console.log`s ? level2 seems to not be an array but an object

Comment: Please post finaldata structure. It seems that level2 at certain point is not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going too deep here:
`const level2 = finalData[i].links[x];`

This makes level2 not an array which makes sort not work.

Remove the index accessor:
`finalData[i].links;`

You will not need the second for loop either.

And use the sort from MDN for strings:

```
// sort by name
items.sort(function(a, b) {
  var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Your loop would look like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < finalData.length; i++) {
    finalData[i].links.sort((a, b) => {
        var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        if (nameA < nameB) {
           return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB) {
           return 1;
        }

        // names must be equal
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because `level2` is not an Array object, it's an array-like [Arguments object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6).

If you can you external library, like [lodash](https://lodash.com), you can sort by using `orderBy` method:

```
_.orderBy(level2, ['name'], ['asc']);
```